# How to disable Nginx logging for localhost or certain ip?

Tags: nginx, logging

I've got several sections in my Nginx config, fcgi for php, upstream for certain URLs etc and I want the `nginx.log` file to no log anything for any query coming from localhost as internal processes just flood it and then get processed by cron scripts.

Any ideas?

I've tried this is it ignores it.

```
location / {
   rewrites......
   if ($host = 127.0.0.1){
     access_log off;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your config is correct, but NginX tends to be a little... crazy? with Ifs. Take a look on it's [If is Evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) wiki page.

Aside from that, instead of trying to disable the log on that condition, try to redirect it to another log, like `/var/log/nginx/access_localhost.log` and see if it helps (link it to `/dev/null` if it works, or just truncate each day).

Also remember that `access_log` diretives (and other directives in NginX) will not be inherited. This is a quote from the NginX mail list (linked from NginX's wiki) about the subject:

> There is no "global" logs in nginx,
>   only "local" ones, either  explicitly
>   defined or inhereted from previous
>   level.
>
> The access_log directive, as all
>   array-type directives in nginx 
>   config, will ignore inherited values
>   if defined at certain level.   I.e. in
>   configuration
>
> http {
>       access_log log1;
>
> ```
> server {
>     server_name  server1;
> }
>
> server {
>     server_name  server2;
>     access_log   log2;
>     ...
> } }
> ```
>
> only server1 will have logging set to
>   log1, while server2 will  have logging
>   set to log2.  If you want server2 to
>   write log into  both log1 and log2 you
>   should say this explicitly, i.e.
>
> ```
> server {
>     server_name  server2;
>     access_log   log1;
>     access_log   log2;
>     ...
> }
> ```